# Angular: *ngIf failing using concatMap with async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs

If I have an `Observable` releasing values over time:

```
values$ = from([1, 2, 3, 'done'])
  .pipe(
    concatMap((x) => of(x).pipe(delay(1000)))
  );
```

And I have a function returning access to that `Observable`:

```
getOutputs(): Observable<'done' | number> {
    return this.values$;
  }
```

And subscribe to the `Observable` through a function in the template using `*ngIf` and `async`:

```
<div *ngIf="getOutputs() | async as val">
  <hello name="{{ val }}"></hello>
</div>
```

The behavior is expected: the browser shows 'Hello 1!', 'Hello 2!', 'Hello 3!', 'Hello done!', with an interval for each of about a second.

If, instead, I store the latest value in a `BehaviorSubject` and cycle all of the values through that `BehaviorSubject` in `ngOnInit`:

```
outputs$ = new BehaviorSubject<number | 'done' | null>(null);
```

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscriptions.add(
      from<[number, number, number, 'done']>([
        1,
        2,
        3,
        'done',
      ]).subscribe((val) => this.outputs$.next(val))
    );
  }
```

The behavior is of course different: the values are all sent to the `BehaviorSubject`, and `outputs$.value` becomes 'done' very quickly. So anything coming along later and subscribing would only get 'done'. Also expected.

If I change `getOutputs()` to use `this.outputs$` instead, I just get 'Hello done!':

```
getOutputs(): Observable<null | 'done' | number> {
    return this.outputs$;
  }
```

But if I add the same `concatMap` used earlier, like this:

```
getOutputs(): Observable<null | 'done' | number> {
    return this.outputs$
    .pipe(
      concatMap((x) => of(x).pipe(delay(1000)))
    );
  }
```

'done' gets sent over and over, once a second (which can be seen through `tap(console.log)`), but the template shows nothing. This is unexpected: I would think that the HTML would show 'Hello done!'.

Why is this happening?

See [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xmeqhg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: I don't want to muddy up the original question, but also want to note that when this.values$ is used from the example, and piped with filter(), a '1' is sent over and over, and *ngIf unexpectedly fails. They probably have the same root cause.


Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ygpaan?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

This is caused by how Angular handles change detection.

Angular will regularly check that your view is up-to-date with the data in your model, and is in fact continuously calling your `getOuputs()` method, once every second!

---

### Angular's Change Detection in a nutshell

Consider your `app.component.html` template:

```html
<div *ngIf="getOutputs() | async as val">
  <hello name="{{ val }}"></hello>
</div>
```

Here, Angular will regularly re-evaluate `getOutputs() | async`, a "couple of times", until your application is in a **stable** state.

However, for each evaluation, you are returning a **new, unique** `Observable`, because you **create** that **new, unique** `Observable` in your `getOutputs` method:

```js
public getOutputs(): Observable</* ... */> {
  return this.outputs$.pipe(
     concatMap(x => of(x).pipe(delay(1000))),
  ); // it's not `this.outputs$`, it's a **new Observable**
}
```

Therefore, if you where to create another member like that:

```
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   private subscriptions = new Subscription();
   private outputs$ = new BehaviorSubject</* ... */>(null);
+  private actualOutputs$ = this.outputs$.pipe(
+    concatMap(x => of(x).pipe(delay(1000))),
+  );

   public getOutputs(): Observable</* ... */> {
+    return this.actualOutputs$;
-    return this.outputs$.pipe(
-       concatMap(x => of(x).pipe(delay(1000))),
-    );
   }
 }
```

(welp, StackOverflow doesn't support `diff` syntax highlighting, sorry about that...)

... then your application would behave exactly as you expect!

---

### Some more exploration

But then why does removing the delay, yet yielding a different `Observable` every time also works?

Let's consider the alternative implementation for `getOutputs` below:

```js
public getOutputs(): Observable</* ... */> {
  return this.outputs$.pipe(
    concatMap(x => of(x)/* .pipe(delay(1000)) */), // no more delay here
  ); // that's a **new** Observable every time.
}
```

It's because I (purposely ) overlooked something earlier:
Angular isn't simply re-evaluating `getOutputs()` until your component is stable, but actually `getOutputs() | async`, which translates roughly as `async(getOutput())` in a pure TypeScript world.

What is happening here is also somewhat simple:
Contrary to the previous case, where the `AsyncPipe`, when having to wait for a `delay`ed `Observble`, won't be definitely stable; that `AsyncPipe` yields a value **immediately** and yields the same (`'done'`) every time; Angular considers your component "stable" and proceeds with updating the view.

If you debug the code attentively (or drop a `console.log` at the top of `getOutputs()`'s body), you can notice that `getOutputs()` is then still called 4 times in rapid succession, one for each evaluation of `async(getOutputs())`.

Switching to a more conservative `changeDetection` strategy for your component as follows:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, // different strategy here
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
```

... would allow `getOutputs()` to only be executed **once** in that case!

Comment: Thank you, that gets me closer to an answer, but I'm still not completely understanding.

If I understand you correctly, then Angular retrieves a new Observable from the function every time it checks for whether the app is stable. Since this is always a new Observable, is Angular therefore never stable, and will continually try and fail to be stable? Is that why it never ends up displaying anything?

It sounds like *ngIf isn't exactly 'failing', but rather is never reaching a state that satisfies it enough to actually allow for creating the element...

Comment: Ah, sorry for somehow managing to have not answered the actual question! Everytime your `getOutputs()` finally yields `'done'` (after a second), the delayed nature of its update will trigger a new change detection cycle by Angular. Then, the pipe will make sure that it still is subscribed to what it should be, it'll call `getOutputs()` again, realise that, woops, it's a new `Observable` stream that it needs to listen to now, it'll subscribe to that, and just as it is about to receive a new value a second later... new Change Detection cycle! it all repeats forever.

Comment: I'm starting to see where I went wrong here. I'm relatively new to using async pipe, but used Observables often in the component logic. In the component logic, if you write a function that returns an Observable and subscribe to it within a Subscription in ngOnInit, everything is fine. That setup happens once, and your pipe will run as necessary. I was trying to use the same pattern with async pipe, which turns out to be less good because you have to design the code with change detection in mind.

In other words, when consuming Observables in .ts, functions are fine. .html, not as much.